# Kotlin: how to pass collection into generic type of a function

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have this abstract function:

```
    abstract fun <T> updateValue(value: T)
```

Now i want a subclass to override it with a collection into the generic type:

```
override fun <List<Int>> updateValue(value: List<Int>)
```

and this does not work. Basic types work just fine (String, Int etc) but when I want to use a collection I do not know the right syntax. This is ok:

```
override fun <String> updateValue(value: String)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override a generic function with a fixed parameter, instead, you may have the type parameter on a class or interface to make it. E.g.

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  abstract fun updateValue(value: T) : Unit
}

///class to accept _only_ List<Int>
class ListClass<List<Int>> {
  override fun updateValue(value: List<Int>) { /*...*/ }
}

/// class to accept _only_ String
class StringClass<String> {
  override fun updateValue(value: String) { /*...*/ }
}
```

The rationale is as follows when you declare a generic function, e.g. `fun <T> updateValue(value: T)` is mean it is supposed to work for every possible `T`. It will not do a pattern matching to find the best suitable match.

You may try checking types in the implementation of the generic function to support a specific case, but in general, it could be hard for collection classes because of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

```
fun <T> updateValue(value: T) {
  when (value) {
    is String -> handleStringValue(value)
    is List<*> -> handleListValue(value)
    else -> handleDefault(value)
  }
}
```

You cannot tell `List<Int>` from `List<String>` here. An `inline fun` with `reified` generics may [help](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you'd actually want to use a generic parameter on the class instead:

```
abstract class Parent<T> {
    abstract fun updateValue(value: T)
}
```

And then extend it to:

```
class Child : Parent<List<Int>> {
    override fun updateValue(value: List<Int>)
}
```

The only reason that the override with `String` works

```
override fun <String> updateValue(value: String)
```

is that `String` is not a type in this context but the name of the generic parameter you used to name `T` before. `List<Int>` however is not a valid name.